# Laravel remove files from storage

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to remove all documents from a customer:

```
        // remove extra documents
        $documents = Document::where('customer_id', $customer->id);
        foreach ($documents as $document) {
            Storage::disk('userfiles')->delete($document->name);
        }
        $documents->delete();
```

Records get deleted from database, but files stay in storage folder.
Filename in database is the same as filename in storage folder. (checked)

I also use the following code in the same method that does work:

```
        Storage::disk('userfiles')->delete($customer->id_card);
```

I'm using Angular as front-end and I'm new to both.

Comment: Have you checked logs? You get absolutely no error? I guess that deleting *non-existing* file (from script point of view) does not throw up, so you better check if the file you are deleting is there.

Comment: The files are there, even checked filenames in folder and in db. In angular, if response is error, I log it to console. But got no errors.

Comment: What I am saying is that the script thinks there are no files, your configuration is not correct. `Psy Shell v0.9.6 (PHP 7.1.14 — cli) by Justin Hileman >>> Storage::disk('local')->delete('nontexisting-file') => false`. You need to check if the file exists I bet your configuration is wrong. It does not error out it fails *gracefully* if you will, thus you have no clue if the deletion was done, you can either catch the value of `->delete(...)` it returns boolean, or you need to check the existence yourself and amend the code to that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution,

```
            // remove extra documents
            $documents = Document::where('customer_id', $customer->id)->get();
            foreach ($documents as $document) {
                Storage::disk('userfiles')->delete($document->name);
                $document->delete();
            }
```

Without `->get()` the `$documents` variable is empty, so it doens't loop.
With `->get()` the `$documents->delete()` doesn't work, so I moved it inside the loop and delete each record on its own with `$document->delete()`